# How to smooth a curve

Tags: r

I have a data like this. Is there any way to smoothen my plot ?

```
cr <- colorRampPalette(col=c("red", "red", "red", "red"), bias=1)
linecols <- cr(3)
x<-c(-1000.000000,-900.000000,-800.000000,-700.000000,-600.000000,-500.000000,-400.000000,-300.000000,-200.000000,-100.000000,0.000000,100.000000,200.000000,300.000000,400.000000,500.000000,600.000000,700.000000,800.000000,900.000000,1000.000000)
y<-c(0.809524,1.000000,1.333333,1.333333,3.285714,7.761905,13.619048,7.571429,14.809524,3.904762,1.857143,2.285714,4.857143,8.571429,2.000000,1.523810,2.714286,0.857143,1.285714,0.857143,1.380952)
plot(x, y,type="l",main="Average",ylab="Average Profile",col=linecols[1],ylim=c(0.809524,14.809524),xaxt="s",yaxt="s",lwd=2)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
lines(x, smooth(y))
```

See `?smooth`.

```
lines(supsmu(x, y))
```

See '?supsmu'.

Beware, smoothing is the devil's business.

Comment: It seems excel smoothing is different from ggplot or R smoothing. Excel doesn't change any shape but R/ggplot does.

Comment: What algorithm/s does Excel use? There is really no end to what you might do for this. You should provide an example, if you think this is an issue.

Answer (score 6):

I'll second @mdsumner 's caution about smoothing (an internet search of "smoothing data bad" returns lots of pages), but I'll offer another solution:

```
plot(lowess(x,y,f=1/3),type="l",col="red")
```

See `?lowess` for more information.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Many smoothers are available.

Here is a smoothing function:

```
trace.smooth<-function(trace, type="Savitsky-Golay", width=10){

  if(type=="lowess"){
    smooth.trace<-with(clean.trace, lowess(x=1:length(trace),
                                   y=trace,
                                   f=width/length(trace),
                                   delta=width/2))$y
  }

  if(type=="moving-average"){
        moving_average<-function(width=10){
        moving.average<-rep(1,width)/width
        return(moving.average)
      }

      moving.average<-moving_average(width)

      smooth.trace<-filter(trace, moving.average)

  }

  if(type=="Savitsky-Golay"){
      # Savitsky-Golay smoothing function 
    savistsky_golay<-function(width=10){
      x<-1:width-width/2
      y<-max(x^2)-x^2
      sg<-y/sum(y)
      return(sg)
    }

    sg<-savistsky_golay(width)

      smooth.trace<-filter(trace, sg)
  }

  return(smooth.trace)
}
```

A solution using [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/)

```
library(ggplot2)

df<-data.frame(x=x, y=y)

qplot(data=df,
      x=x,
      y=y,
      geom=c("line", "point"))+
      geom_smooth(se=F)
```

[image: plot with smooth]

you can add a method argument to [geom_smooth](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_smooth.html)(method="loess")

method: smoothing method (function) to use, eg. lm, glm, gam, loess, rlm

you can fine tune using [stat_smooth](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/stat_smooth.html)